# How to stop one of the click functions

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click

I have a button with `onClick="clickState()"` part attached. Now, in clickState I have specified what will happen once user click the item for the first time. But then, I have nested another click event that will trigger another functionality when user click it for the second time.

The thing is, code works, but the console log records one state twice because the second click also run the 'first click' function. In other words I want to stop function once it has been triggered once but I don't want to stop function which is inside of it. Also, which I just realized, there is small problem with deleting picture inside . Console said "button.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at button.html:55" Why this happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            #btn {
            color:#ffed00;
            line-height:40px;
            height:40px;
            vertical-align:middle;
            width:280px;
            border-radius:3px;
            border:2px #000 solid;
            background: #00a1e0;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00a1e0, #00a1e0 60%, #005578 100%); 
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#00a1e0 ,#00a1e0 60%, #005578 100%); 
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00a1e0, #00a1e0 60%, #005578 100%); 
            background: linear-gradient(#00a1e0, #00a1e0 60%, #005578 100%); 
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
            font-family:Roboto;
            font-size:16px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
        }

        #btn.active {
            color:#00a1e0;
            border:2px solid #00a1e0;
            background: #000000;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #005578 40%, #005578 100%); 
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#000000, #005578 40%, #005578 100%); 
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000000, #005578 40%, #005578 100%); 
            background: linear-gradient(#000000, #005578 40%, #005578 100%); 
        }
        #btn:disabled {
            color:#999999;
            border:2px #999999 solid;
            background:#cccccc;
        }
    </style>        
    <script>
        var currentState = "Initial button";
        function clickState() {
            if (currentState == "Loading button") 
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
                btn.innerHTML = '<img src="loading.gif" id="imgLoading" alt="Loading" width="25" height="25" />';
                currentState = "Loading button";

                setTimeout (function() {
                    btn.className += " active";
                    btn.removeChild(document.getElementById("imgLoading"));
                    currentState = "Hit button";
                    console.log(currentState);

                        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        btn.disabled = true;
                        currentState = "Disabled button";
                        btn.removeChild(document.getElementById("imgLoading"));
                        console.log(currentState);
                    });
                }, 5000);

                console.log(currentState);
            }
        }
        console.log(currentState);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="clickState();">Opt me in</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the event listener once the button has been clicked.

Try this:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    btn.removeEventListener("click"); // remove event listener
    btn.disabled = true;
    currentState = "Disabled button";
    btn.removeChild(document.getElementById("imgLoading"));
    console.log(currentState);
});
```

Comment: I tried this (didn't work) but hey, won't it remove click we just did?

Comment: It should remove the event listener after it has fired.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `onClick="clickState()"` to the element. Try adding the event listener in JS.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", clickState);
```